# 27" iMac won't stay asleep

Tags: imac, sleep-wake

My 27" iMac wakes up from sleep randomly, even though I went through the "energy saver" preference pane, and bluetooth is only active for my mouse and keyboard.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you please run `pmset -g assertions` in Terminal (`/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`) and post the output in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/Applications/Utilities/` run Terminal.app, then type this command:

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"
```

What do you see?

The codes listed here might give you a clue as to what is going on: http://osxdaily.com/2010/07/17/why-mac-wakes-from-sleep/

Comment: ehc2 appears about once an hour, i tried unchecking "wake using bluetooth mouse and keyboard" but didnt change a thing overnight.

Answer (score -3):

go to safari in the top left hand corner and-prefrences-enable javascript. and turn down your brightness and turn it off then turn it back on and it shouldnt do that again.